# Can't run my project in eclipse because java force closes

Tags: java

I hope this is more worded to be on topic because me not having the ability to code because of a java issue is off topic apparently.

When I try to run my project in eclipse. Eclipse just sais  at the bottom with no stack trace. If I compile the jar file and run it with javaw it does nothing. If I run it with java it brings up the java(tm) platform has stopped working.

What I have tried:

- Changing association of .jar to use java and javaw
- tried uninstalling java and reinstalling
- installing windows updates
- restarting my computer
- cleaned registry
- running it in command prompt (just pulls up a window saying "Java(tm) platform se binary has stopped working." There is no stacktrace inside the prompt either.)
- scanned for any malware/viruses
- using the "fix and restore windows 8 option"

My system:

- Windows 8 :/
- java 7 latest 64 bit Update 13
- java SE dev kit 7 Update 13 (was happening before I installed it)
- 16 gigs of ram
- I can give you more info if need be.

Jars work on my other computer just fine.

edit: Still no luck. 8 out of 8 places I asked for help I got down voted. Looks like im not developing anymore.... Thanks.

Comment: Please show Your log.

Comment: there is no log. no stacktrace. nothing.

Comment: Then you should tell more about your project, maybe post a small SSCCE that shows that behaviour or give us something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a known [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6772139) with this message, the workaround should be to disable d3d acceleration by adding this as a VM argument: -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false